# Simple function not being defined. Don't see any syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run this script through a JS lint... When I try to execute `sendLogin()` the console returns that it hasn't been defined. Why?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#register-fields').hide();

    function reCenter(){
        $('.login-window').center($('.wrapper'));
    }

    $('.login-window').center($('.wrapper'));

    $(window).resize(reCenter);

    var creds = new Object();

    function popLogCreds(creds){
        creds.username = $("#username-field").val();
        creds.password = $("#password-field").val();
    }

    function sendLogin(){

        popLogCreds();

        var loginCredentials= {
        "username":creds.username,
        "password":creds.password };

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: loginCredentials,
            dataType: "json"
        });

        request.always(function(data) {

            console.log(data); 

            var ParsedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            sessionStorage.username=ParsedData.username;
            sessionStorage.password=ParsedData.password;
            sessionStorage.fname=ParsedData.fname;
            sessionStorage.lname=ParsedData.lname;
            sessionStorage.rank=ParsedData.rank;

        });

    }


});
</script>
```

Comment: If you try and call the function outside that `$(document).ready()` scope, it will not be available. You could try namespacing it, or making your function calls within that scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined it using a function declaration inside another function (the anonymous one that you pass to `ready()` as an argument). Function declarations are locally scoped so it isn't a global.

Calling it from the console would only work if it was a global.

You can copy it to the global scope with:

```
window.sendLogin = sendLogin;
```

Alternatively, move it (and any functions it calls that are also locally scoped, and so on down the line) to the global scope (i.e. outside of all other functions).

Comment: +1 for that last reminder. I was going to move the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the sendlogin() function out of `document.ready()`. Then you can call it from `$(document).ready`

Comment: Thanks! Never realized this.

Comment: Then it will promptly fail because it calls `popLogCreds` which is *also* locally scoped.

Comment: Aha, I'll have to move them both then. I should change my practice and define all global functions in a separate functions.js file. @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `sendLogin()` in `document.ready` and it becomes it scope and could not be called from global scope. Define the `sendLogin` outside `document.ready`, As you are calling `popLogCreds` from `sendLogin`, you should `popLogCreds`  defined out side of document.ready as pointed by @Quentin

Comment: Ok, I've never had that problem before. Thank you.

Comment: If you define it outside the function you pass to ready, and make no other changes, then it will still fail because it calls `popLogCreds` which is *also* locally scoped.